# Hear about your father passing away or hear about your father'passing

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Would you explain for me the different between 
  " hear about your father passing away" and " ...your father's passing.
In my opinion, it is reasonable tho use " ... your father's passing because after preposition "about" we should use a noun or noun phrase.
I am wondering if it is right.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please include any research you may have done before posting this question. If you need assistance in drafting a question, please consult our Help page—[How ask a question.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm under the impression that "passing" (or "passing away") is passé anymore (at least in the US).  "I was saddened to hear of the death of your father" would be more idiomatic, and (oddly) seem more personal and less formulaic.

Comment: Both forms are equally correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a question of idiom, not any kind or right or wrong.

For whatever reason, some idioms or dialects use '… your father passing away', some use '… your father's passing' and some '… your father's passing away.'

Strictly speaking 'your father passing away' might mean something like 'the passing away that your father did' while '… your father's passing away' is something like 'the passing away that happened to your father', with which simple '… passing…'is synonymous.

To take it to an extreme most of us might say '… his late father' while a few dialects clearly prefer '… his father, who is late.'

In all those cases what's the difference, outside a textbook?